# Torbirdy looks for port 9150 whereas Tor daemon works on 9050

Tags: torbirdy, torsocks

I see in documentation of TorBirdy [everywhere](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy#SetupSteps) that it needs to look for Tor Daemon on port 9150 but Tor daemon on my system(Ubuntu 14.04) runs on 9050 by default. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of TorBirdy seems to think that everyone uses Tor Browser. This is the part of Tor, an end user would normally install and it uses port 9150 by default. If you have the Tor daemon installed, it uses port 9050. You should use this port of course.